# Как правильно читать термин?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, терминология

В работе постоянно пользуюсь термином "объект по использованию отходов". Сам термин выглядит так: "объекты по использованию отходов – сооружения (комплекс сооружений) и оборудование, специально предназначенные для использования отходов".
Вопрос в том, возможно ли "разделение" данного термина на два, т.е. "сооружения (комплекс сооружений), специально предназначенные для использования отходов" и "оборудование, специально предназначенное для использования отходов" и считать их равноценными?

Comment: Можно, если объясните, как сооружение без оборудования будет использовать отходы.

Comment: Сооружение без оборудования – никак, тут вы совершенно правы. Но оборудование-то без сооружения очень даже прекрасно может это делать, в смысле перерабатывать отходы.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что по отдельности этот термин читать нельзя. Иначе это серьёзный огрех со стороны автора термина. Чуть меньшим грехом было бы упомянуть в понятном контексте "комплекс сооружений" в качестве этого "объекта", но не само оборудование (на мой взгляд).

Для того, чтобы термин читался по отдельности он должен был определяться хотя бы так: "**объекты** по использованию отходов ... ".

Comment: прошу прощения за свою невнимательность, термин выглядит именно так: "объекты по использованию отходов – ..."

Comment: В таком случае я принципиальных проблем не вижу – разве что в контексте могут проявиться. В том смысле, что мне оно глаз не режет (исходя из моего опыта чтения технической литературы). Но давайте подождём, что более опытные участники посоветуют.